# CATransformLayer: A Black Hole For Touches?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Im just looking for some confirmation perhaps with documentation or a source.

I know the docs say that you can't send hittest to a CATransformLayer as it cannot map 3D to 2D coords.   My question is.. is that it?  Is a CATransformLayer a black hole for touches.  Once I put a layer into that CATransformLayer hierarchy... hasta la vista to touching it directly?

Does anyone have a workaround or any black magic to share?

Comment: There's never any sense of "touching [a CALayer] directly." Touches are a UIKit thing. I suspect you're referring to CALayer's `hitTest:` API. I can't prove a negative, but based on years of working w/ Core Animation, my expectation would be that if such hit-testing were straightforward or performance-trivial, it would already be in the CA API. In a conventional 3D environment, one method for doing this sort of think is called "ray picking". Perhaps reading up on that might shed light on how you might implement your own hit checking.

Comment: thanks.  correct on the touch CALayer.  I have a view's layer hosted inside a calayer. trying to touch the UIView.  Good idea on the Ray Picking.